# Why size=0 not working when I use aggregations of elasticsearch in python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```
body={
  'size':0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_App": {
                "terms": {
        "field":"B" ,
        'size':5000
      },
        'aggs':{
                'group_by_IP':{
                        'terms':{
                                'field':'A',
                                'size':5000}}}

      }

  }
}        

res= client.search(index='A',body=body)
```

I want to only get aggregations result but when I use size=0(1st) the result of res still contain all result.

Why ???

Comment: Try with `'size':'0'` i.e. 0 as a string instead of number

Comment: Continuing the above comment by @Val, 
try "size":0